# Limit the jQuery select2 maximum selected options

Tags: javascript, limit, jquery-select2, uncaught-exception

I have referred to this docs provided by select2 jQuery plugin. 
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

But when I use this code to limit the number of options a user can select at a time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select2").select2({ maximumSelectionSize: 2 });
    });
```

And here is the html of select tag:

```
  <select id="store-name" name="state[]" class="select2-select-00 span6" multiple size="5"
            data-placeholder="Store" style="height:25px;">


        <?php foreach ($this->Store->get_all_stores_names() as $row) {

        //print_r($row);
          echo '<option value="' . $row->name . '"> ' . $row->name . '</option>';
        }
        ?>

    </select>
```

When I try to limit it, I get this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'select2'

Why? I mean the select2 works fine which means that it's js files are being loaded, then why I am unable to limit it?

Comment: I don't see the `.select2` class in you html

Comment: I have even tried it with the id selector like this:
jQuery("#store-name").select2({ maximumSelectionSize: 2 });
still same error.

Answer (score 7):

Use **maximumSelectionLength** like so:

```
$("#selectQQQ").select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 3
});
```

**Extension**

Select2 has [`data-* attributes`](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes)

Meaning, that you can set your `maximumSelectionLength` parameter as HTML5 data attributes like so:

```
<select data-placeholder="Select a state" data-maximum-selection-length="2" ...>
```

Comment: is it possible to add data-maximumSelectionLength="2" ?

Comment: @AbhiBurk, is it not working? What is your error message?\

Comment: no error and it worked using this on an element `data-maximum-selection-length="2"`

Comment: You are right, I forget to put a data attribute way to set it in the answer. Thank you.